# How do you reorder widgets in Glade?

Tags: application-development, glade

How can I reorder widgets in the Glade widget tree?

For example, assume I have a Glade application that contains this partial tree:

```
box1 (GtkBox)
|--button1 (GtkButton)
|--button2 (GtkButton)
|--button3 (GtkButton)
```

How can I swap the position of e.g. button1 with e.g. button2, so that button2 will be above button1 in the UI?

Comment: You're looking for re-parenting.  Post a more complete code sample and glade file for an answer instead of a comment.  An example answer that provides the context the question should have: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155298/how-do-i-add-a-notebook-to-a-box-in-a-vbox/155345#155345

Comment: https://gist.github.com/strugee/5330567. i don't have any logic hooked up yet for buttons and stuff.

Comment: it has one additional .py file that shouldn't be getting imported from anything. other than that it's a generic quickly application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation, it appears that you cannot modify the order from the widget tree panel. However, you can still modify order in the visual editor.

In the toolbar, there are a couple of buttons for selecting cursor modes. Click the button right after the cursor. It should have four arrows. Then click on the widget that you want to move, and drag it where you want to move it to.

Comment: Or you can change the `position` property in the `packing` tab of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this, and found that the accepted answer is incorrect, or at least is no longer correct in current versions of Glade.

From within Glade, you can adjust the `Position` property under the `Packing` tab, whose value determines the index of the widget within its parent.

So in OP's example:

```
box1 (GtkBox)
|--button1 (GtkButton) (Position: 0)
|--button2 (GtkButton) (Position: 1)
|--button3 (GtkButton) (Position: 2)
```

Each button would have a `Position` value of 0, 1, and 2 respectfully. If you were to change the `Position` value of `button2` to 0, it would move it up and `button1` would then have a `Position` value of 1, which changes the order both in the tree and how it is displayed in the designer and final application.

```
box1 (GtkBox)
|--button2 (GtkButton) (Position: 0)
|--button1 (GtkButton) (Position: 1)
|--button3 (GtkButton) (Position: 2)
```

Comment: This worked for me in Glade version 3.38.2.

Comment: When was this feature added? It doesn't exist in v3.22.2-1 (using Linux Mint 20.1).

Comment: @ajgringo619 I am not sure at exactly which point it was added, I am using 3.38.2-1 on Arch, though I believe it has existed for at least a few minor versions before that. Would probably have to slog through the changelogs for an exact version. Does Mint offer any "bleeding edge" version that you could use instead of the stable one in the official repos?

Comment: Since my comment I installed the flatpak version (v3.38) and none of my widgets have a Position property.

Comment: I should rephrase that - none of the widgets have a Position setting under Packing.